# Can I write a symbol elementary row transformation by Tex?

Tags: matrix, latex

I want to write a symbol elementary row transformation by tex like an 'r' on the ~ symbol. I try to use `\sim^r` or `\thicksim^r`, but the 'r' just in the top right corner of ~, just like a superscript. [image: The example style]

Are there any packages to make this symbols output? I use Markdown to do this before. As Chirs advised in comments, maybe use Tex to do this is better. So I edit the question from Markdown to latex.
I want to write like the picture shows, but I can't find a good way. Can anyone help me? Thanks. I'm not native English speaker. Please forgive my awful expression.
[image: example1]

As the picture above, I use `\Huge` to `\sim`, the symbol seems to be overstriking. As my Linear Algebra book, the symbol shows the picture below. Can we get an affection like that?
[image: The symbol in my book]

Comment: It looks like your question is really about [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) / [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), not [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). Please edit your tags appropriately and / or ask on [tex.se].

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I know in Tex we can use package. And in markdown we can't. I would like to know if I can write this in markdown. And add a Tex tag is a good idea.

Comment: You can't do _anything_ like what you have shown above in Markdown. It has no support whatsoever for mathematical notation. Markdown is a very limited format [designed for writing prose](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html): "Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of HTML tags." `\sim^r` and `\thicksim^r` are just plain text, holding no meaning in Markdown. If you're getting any mathematical notation in your output you're not using Markdown. (Maybe you mean _R_ Markdown?)

Comment: Thanks. I know what you mean now. I use Typora to edit my text. And it is using Github Flavored Markdown. Maybe I should try Tex to write?

Comment: Even GitHub Flavored Markdown doesn't support mathematical notation, and I don't see any existing Typora questions on SO. I suspect you'll get better answers on [tex.se].

Comment: Thank you. I will edit my question description to search a good way to make this symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining [this reference by Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273005/49683) and [this other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119098/49683) by Gonzalo Medina, I worked out this minimal code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c}
r_1 \leftrightarrow r_2 \\ \sim \\ r_3 \times \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{array}{c}
\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}{r_2 \leftrightarrow r_3}{r_3-2r_1} \\ \sim \\ r_4-3r_1
\end{array}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e \\
a & b & c & d & e
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The interesting part of it is to combine `array` environment and `genfrac` command for the sake of:

- vertical alignment,
- font size ([the attribute `{0}` of  `genfrac` is to provide `displaystyle`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/genfrac.htm)).

Comment: Thank you for giving a method. I try this, but it seems that the symbol `~` is small that can't hold the description above.

Comment: @fish-404 Ok, try to change `\sim` to `\text{\large$\sim$}`. If `\large` is not large enough, try `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge` or `\Huge`.

Comment: Your advice done! Although the symbol seems a little different from other fonts.

Comment: I mean the symbol is enlarged and if we use `\huge`, the symbol seems be overstnking. Can we just let the symbol be longer but not higher. I will add a picture in my question to show what I mean later.

Comment: @fish-404 seen your updated question...i'll have a deeper look into it